# Is it possible to use counsel-yank-pop (or something similar) to get the job done of pasting from the clipboard-ring in the mini-buffer?

Tags: minibuffer, yank, kill-ring, counsel

This is my emacs [init file](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/blob/main/.emacs.d/init.el). As you see, I use command `counsel-yank-pop`. And I even did a keybinding for it with:

```lisp
;; =counsel-yank-pop= enhances built-in =yank-pop=.
(global-set-key (kbd "M-y") 'counsel-yank-pop)
```

In general, it works as a handy way to see everything in my clipboard ring and add text to regular buffers (like scratch buffer and buffers with files).

When the command is executed, I can see a list of options in the mini-buffer and choose one of them with fuzzy-matching:

[image]

Unfortunately, sometimes I want to paste something *from the kill ring onto the mini-buffer space*. By habit, I press `M-y` while typing on the mini-buffer but this creates a contradiction that is echoed by Emacs:

> Command attempted to use mini-buffer while in minibuffer

Is there a way to "dribble" this problem? Is there a way to iterate over the kill ring in the mini-buffer without using the mini-buffer?

Maybe another command? Or using another Emacs package?

I am open to broad suggestions.

Obs.: the same problem happens with `yank-pop` which is a default command.

Comment: Have you tried setting (or binding in some command definition) `enable-recursive-minibuffers` to `t`? Does that take care of your problem - it lets you use a new minibuffer (e.g. ask you some other question) when you're in the minibuffer.

Comment: If this is only about the use of `counsel-yank-pop` then maybe try advising it to set `enable-recursive-minibuffers` to `t` around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Drew](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/105/drew) pointed out in a comment, adding this to my init file did the trick:

```lisp
;; It lets you use a new minibuffer when you're in the minibuffer
(setq enable-recursive-minibuffers t)
```

Thank you for me helping another time, [@Drew](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/105/drew).